# filter csv data using python without pandas

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I wanted to filter based on flat type and mean of resale price i.e. room5, I'm trying to filter based on the resale price values for 5-room flats. However when I tried to 'print' room5, it's empty list. Which part did I miss out?

[![Code with printed data][1]][1]

Comment: if you ask again the same question then you should at least put data as text. Or create minimal working code so we could copy it and run to test.

Comment: Sorry what data do I need to put as text to facilitate help?

Comment: data which you have on images. Always put code, data and error messages as text, not images. Python can't read information from images.

Comment: I had already added the dataset in pastebin :) Thanks for the guidance, as well as upload the spyder export in text format.

Comment: do you really read it with `genfromtxt` ? All code looks like you use only `pandas`

Comment: It's from numpy package genfromtxt. I had never learnt panda and never import panda package. Everything is purely in the code I copied, other  than the first statement 'import numpy as np'

Comment: BTW: in data you have `5-room` but in code you use `5 room`

Comment: as I rember in comment to previous question you already had solution `room5 = roomprice2013[ roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room' ]` and it was even with `sum()`  - `roomprice2013[roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room']['price'].sum()` and it works for me

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I might have miss out that message, I thought of creating a new one cos the initial question was different from this one. I don't wanna confuse those with helped me. But it worked now. Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: Hi, can I understand why is there two layers of roomprice 2013? room5 = roomprice2013[ roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room' ], what does the first layer looks for and what does the second layer works for?

Comment: first layer returns only list with `True/False` - try `print( roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room' )` and second layer uses these `True/False` to skip rows (for `False`) and keep only rows which you need. BTW: you can assing first layer to variable and use it many times to get the same rows later - when they have different values and you could get them using again `roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room'`. OR you can use this list `True/False` to get rows with other array with the same number of rows.

Comment: in answer I added example which shows and uses this list with `True/False`. You can alwasy create this list in different way (ie using `random`) and use it to get only some values.

Answer (score 0):

To get rooms

```
room5 = roomprice2013[ roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room' ]
print(room5)
```

to get sum

```
room5_sum = roomprice2013[ roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room' ]['price'].sum()
print(room5_sum)
```

---

Working example.

I used `io.StringIO` to simulate file so everyone can copy and run example without downloding file with data.

```
import numpy as np
import io

s = io.StringIO('''quarter,town,flat_type,price
2013-Q2,Bedok,1-room,na
2013-Q2,Bedok,2-room,-
2013-Q2,Bedok,3-room,172000
2013-Q2,Bedok,4-room,224500
2013-Q2,Bedok,5-room,332000
2013-Q2,Bedok,Executive,420000''')

data = np.genfromtxt(s, skip_header=1, dtype=[('quarter','U10'),('town','U20'), ('flat_type','U10'), ('price','i8')], delimiter =',', missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values='0')

data_2013 = data[np.isin(data['quarter'], ['2013-Q1','2013-Q2','2013-Q3','2013-Q4'],['flat_type'])]
print(data_2013)

roomprice2013 = data_2013[['flat_type','price']]
print(roomprice2013)

room5 = roomprice2013[roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room']
print(room5)

room5_sum = roomprice2013[roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room']['price'].sum()
print(room5_sum)
```

---

**EDIT:** internal `roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room'` gives only list with `True/False` which you can use (even many times) to keep only needed rows.

```
mask = (roomprice2013['flat_type'] == '5-room')  # it works without () but it is more readable with ()
print(mask) 
# [False False False False  True False]

room5 = roomprice2013[mask]
print(room5)

room5_sum = roomprice2013[mask]['price'].sum()
print(room5_sum)
```